# Alt+F8 or resize window causes X server display Freeze

Tags: linux, redhat, x11, freeze, gdm

Our project is based on Linux Redhat 7 and disabled the "gdm" service.
and when the user tries to **resize the window** which is based on the X window, the program will suddenly freeze, until the user has done the resize operation.
The resize can also be triggered by pressing **alt+F8**.

the freeze is causing the X canvas to stop refreshing and leaves a static picture on the screen.

[here is the video](https://www.youtube.com/shorts/3lXJLVkFOp8) showing the problem.

Has anyone ever encountered a similar situation?
Is there any solution to this problem?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: It sounds like your program does not have proper event processing.

Comment: Looks like your program is suspending itself during the resize. May need to check event handling/processing.

Comment: But as I resize the gnome-terminal or xterm window, the program will also be suspended.